# Catch a JavaScript syntax error in a bash script

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, pipe, nashorn

I have a bash script in Jenkins which uses Nashorn engine to perform a little bit of JavaScript.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

"$JAVA_HOME/bin/jjs" -scripting allKeys.js | sort > resultKeys
```

The allKeys.js script loads another script from external location and then prints some values:

```
bundlesUrl="https://address.to/bundles.js";
load(bundlesUrl);

for (var bundle in bundles) {
    if (bundles.hasOwnProperty(bundle)) {
        for (var key in bundles[bundle]) {
            print(bundle + "\t" + key + "\t\t\"" + bundles[bundle][key] + "\"");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the JavaScript file specified in bundlesUrl may sometimes contain improperly escaped special characters. This of course produces a syntax error.

The `jjs` prints that there was a Syntax error, but the bash script continues.

What I would like to do is somehow catch that syntax error and exit the bash script with code 1 so that the Jenkins build marks as failed.

What are some good ways of achieving this?

EDIT: I found out that I can do this with a `set -e`

Comment: Doesn't `jjs` specify an error code on a unhandled/syntax exception?

Comment: In the Jenkins console log I see only a message from `jjs` that there was a Syntax error and then the bash script continues on. What I want to do is exit the script there and then.

Answer (score 0):

jjs exits with non-zero exit code on error (see also http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/17cc754c8936/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/tools/Shell.java ). So you should be able to check $? in your shell script just after jjs command.

Comment: I think the issue here may be that I am using `sort` on that command, so the last executed command is that, not `jjs`.